# Android notification click

Tags: android

I am running a service which is popping notification on getting a new task. If I close my app it's running in the background and pop up a notification. What I would like to do is, when I click on that notification, open the app. Can I do that ? How ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding an intent to your notification:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourAppActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "headline", "body msg", contentIntent);
    notifcationMgr.notify(id, notification);
```

Just replace YourAppActivity with the activity you want to launch.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So it will go to that Intent on click ?

Comment: Yes. If you click the notification after pulling down your notification bar, it'll launch that Intent.

Comment: do i need to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP ?